# Should dependencies in grunt plugins be declared as dependencies or devDependencies

Tags: gruntjs, npm, package

I'm building a grunt plugin. That plugin needs some other packages to function, while some are only needed in testing.

Which go under devDependencies and which go under regular dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your grunt-plugin basically isnt anything else than a node-module.

you should apply the same rules for dependencies like for a "normal" node-module, which means that everything you need to `test/build/deploy` (or whatever you want to do) your package should reside inside the `devDependencies`, and everything which is needed that your plugin actually works (stuff you `require` in your task!) should go into regular `dependencies`!